# KafkaTableSink : How to use it?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, sbt, apache-flink, flink-sql

This is the table:

```
val res: Table = tenv.sqlQuery(
 """
   |select event.ID,event.locationID, event.temp
   |from event
   |JOIN patt
   |ON event.ID = patt.ID
   |AND event.temp >= patt.temperature
   |""".stripMargin
)
```

This is the schema i want result in:

```
 res.toAppendStream[Event].print("Alert for these location")

 case class Event(ID: Int, locationID: String, temp: Double)
```

I want to make Kafka010TableSink:

```
  val tableSink = new Kafka010TableSink("ask","Output", properties, new FlinkFixedPartitioner[])
```

what goes in schema and Serialization Schema , I'm getting error with FlinkFixedPartitioner.